# How can I stop WiFi and Bluetooth from opening on each restart?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, bluetooth

I have a utility in Samsung Control Centre to turn off my Bluetooth and WiFi connections. But when I restart my system, Bluetooth and WiFi again come up. I don't want them to come up each time. I hardly use them.

Answer (score 0):

Run the msconfig.exe utility from the start-menu. Then click on the services tab and check mark the "Hide all Microsoft Services". Your Samsung wifi & bluetooth startup items must be there, remove them by clearing the checkboxes and click ok. They will not start up automatically with next restart.

If you want them to start again, follow the same process again and revert the cleared checkboxes.